# Does null=True imply default=None for models?

Tags: django, django-models, null, django-1.7

When allowing database fields of a Django model to be NULL using `null=True`, is there default value guaranteed to be NULL by default? Or do I have to speficy this manually:

```
report = models.FileField(upload_to='reports', null=True, default=None)
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I couldn't found anything about it in the documentation about [models fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#model-field-types).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite:

**django/db/models/fields/__init__.py**

```
class NOT_PROVIDED:
    pass

class Field(RegisterLookupMixin):
    # some code
    def __init__(..., default=NOT_PROVIDED, ...):
```

which basically means it is whatever it is in database. For example if you create your table and you set default value directly in database (without altering models), then it will use the value from the database.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this will result in NULL in common databases if not explicitly changed, right?

Comment: @danijar Yes, that's correct. I've never heard about database that would do that differently.

Comment: Alright. By the way, can you say whether fields with `null=False` are set to `0`, `''`, and so on?

Comment: @danijar Not sure, but I think that it will throw an exception (on save) if you don't set the field. Test it.

Comment: Last question, are `null=True` fields automatically `blank=True`?

Comment: @danijar No, `null` is used on the database side while `blank` is used for serving forms to the client. Any combination of these two is valid.

Comment: Defaulting `blank` to true is `null` is true would be a reasonable default I thought. Thank you, you made the parameters much clearer to me.

Comment: @danijar I agree with you, unfortunetly that's not how it is. :) No problem, feel free to post more questions if you ever have a need.